# Where can I listen to a General American Accent on the Internet so I can learn it?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, accent

Any Youtube Channels, Movies, News, Radio, Audiobooks?

Do all of them speak with a General American Accent?

How can I be sure It is 100% General American Accent not just 90% of it? I will imitate 100% of the content. I don't want to imitate the accent that is not a General American Accent. But the problem is I can't tell what American accent they are speaking with. When I watch this [video](https://youtu.be/UcxByX6rh24), most of them sound the same to me.

Comment: Most US accents are similar to each other, and GA is a group of closely related accents (arguably incl. Canada). The most important accents to exclude from consideration would be southern ones. On TV or in a movie, if the actor is playing a character from the southern US, you should assume their accent is non-GA. For good measure, you may also want to assume their accent is non-GA if the *actor* is from the southern US (or from the UK/Ireland/Aus.), even if the character is (as far as you know) from the northern US. As for the news, on mainstream TV the anchor is highly likely to use GA.

Comment: The reality is that there is no GA. This is coming from an American.

Comment: Watch Netflix movies. Watch out for Brooklyn, New York and New Jersey accents.

Answer (score 1):

The best (and most prolific) examples of a General American Accent are US national news anchors and correspondents—though notably not the people they may interview. Local news in the Midwest (except Chicago) and California should also have the same general accent. Do *not* emulate local news from the Northeast, the South or Chicago.

Most other American television, movies and audiobooks should have the same general accent, unless the characters are scripted with a specific accent to make it obvious (to an American audience, at least) that they’re from a specific place. If you can’t hear the difference yet, stick to the news until you can.

Radio and YouTube are full of regional accents, which might be good for listening practice but not for emulating.